# Django Access Primary Model Attribute with select_related

Tags: python, django

I have two models `Site` and `Metric` for which `Metric` has a `ForeignKey` to `Site`.

I am trying to get a QuerySet object that has both `Site.name` and the `Metric` attributes I want.

`Metric.objects.all().select_related('site')`

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your queryset, Django loads the metrics and their related sites at the same time.

```
metrics = Metric.objects.all().select_related('site')
```

You can then loop through the queryset, either in the view or the template, and access the site attributes via the `site` foreign key.

```
for metric in metric:
    print(metric.field1)  # field on metric model
    print(metric.site)  # related site
    print(metric.site.name)  # name of related site
```

Comment: There's not an obvious way to include other field like that. You could include `'site__name'` in [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values), but you might not like that as the key name.

Answer (score 1):

`select_related` is just an optimization to reduce the number of SQL queries. So, `Metric.objects.all().select_related('site')` will just return all of your `Metric` objects more efficiently. From there you can iterate over the `Metric` queryset and do things with the `Site`. Ie.

```
my_first_metric = Metric.objects.all().select_related('site').first()
# my_first_metric.site.name will be the name of the site associated with that metric
```

Comment: Thanks Miestro, but unfortunately that just returns the `__str__` for `Metric`.

Comment: What returns the `__str__`? `my_first_metric`? If you want the site then do `my_first_metric.site`